# A class to add and select players within a database

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysql, pdo

I have a question and want to know if my class is considered object oriented.

```
class Player {

    private $db

    function __construct($db) {

        $this->db = $db;

    }

    public function set_player($name, $position, $number, $team) {

        try {

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO players SET playername = :playername, position = :position, teamid = :teamid, jersey = :jersey';
            $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':playername', $name);
            $s->bindValue(':teamid', $team);
            $s->bindValue(':position', $position);
            $s->bindValue(':jersey', $number);
            $s->execute();

        } catch (PDOEXception $e) {

            echo 'Could not add player, please try again.';
            exit();

        }

    }

    public function get_player($id) {

        $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM players WHERE id =' . $id);
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $row;

    }

}
```

In another file  I will use this class in this way

```
include_once('./includes/global.php');

$player = new Player($pdo);

$player->set_player(Chris, Forward, 13, 1);

echo $player->get_player(1)->playername;
echo $player->get_player(1)->position;
```

Comment: Regarding OOP designs you might be interested to read [this article](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html) about table mapping techniques. And no, your class isn't considered good object oriented design.

Comment: Don't forget to prepare *all* your statements, including `$id`!

Answer (score 4):

Calling `get_player` twice is not a good idea, as each time a db query is necessary.

As you are asking about OOP: You could add an actual `Player` object, which contains `playername`, `position`, etc as fields. Your current class could then be renamed `PlayerDAO` or something, and would then return a player object.

The main advantage would be that a concrete object is easier to use than an anonymous one (classes are to some degree self-documenting, while you can't be sure what an anonymous object actually contains).

**Misc**

- don't die or echo in classes, it makes code less flexible and harder to reuse, as the calling code cannot try to recover.
- `get_player` and `set_player` could be renamed to `get` and `set` as the class is already called `player`.
- It would probably also be good to rename `set` to `save` or similar, as it makes more explicit that there is some kind of database interaction (`set` sounds as if a private field is set).

Comment: thanks for the feedback just started learning OOP in php so i was curious

Answer (score 3):

> I have a question and want to know if my class is considered object oriented.

No, your class can't be considered object oriented, because it violates some basic rules:

- **Data encapsulation**
  Your `Player` class just operates on primitive data items, directly exposes raw database query results (`row`) respectively.
- **Encapsulation/separation of behaviour**
  Your `Player` class accesses the database table directly, echoes error messages directly to the console and exits the program immediately on failure.

What you'll actually need to make up a good object oriented design requires more than just a single class.

In your particular case it's mainly about implementing an appropriate O/R mapping as described in [this article](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html).

In brief:

- You should have a `Player` class that just encapsulates the data and provides operations that directly relate to the data it encapsulates (including getter/setter functions for the private data members).
- You should have a separate `PlayerTableMapper` class, that provides all of the operations (CRUD == **C**reate, **R**ead, **U**pdate, **D**elete), that interact with the corresponding database table

As you can see from the article linked above, that's a pretty broad topic, so excuse me if I'm stopping at this point and don't replicate all of the points to obey in particular.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am noticing that I have a lot to learn now that im seeing this word Mapping alot. Ill keep reading into it until i grasp whats going on. @πάντα ῥεῖ